# Загрузка скриптов после выполнения определенной функции

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, отправляет данные, в зависимости от посетителя я перенаправляю его на другой поддомен.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();


var url = 'https://example/handler.php';
var params = 'key=' + 'XXX' + "&value=" + 'XXX';
http.open('POST', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.location.href = http.responseText;
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Изначально есть страница в `index.php`, но если мне нужно перенапрвить его на другой домен?

Получается у меня идет загрузка `index.php`, а потом другая страница, которая вернулась с подзапроса.

Как можно заблокировать дальнейшее выполнени скриптов, html, css, script и подождать выполнение запроса от сервера, а потом либо дальше продолжить, либо перенаправить?

Пробовал сделать так:

```
r();
async function r() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();


    var url = 'https://example/handler.php';
    var params = 'key=' + 'xxx' + "&value=" + 'xxx';
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.onreadystatechange = await function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            document.location.href = http.responseText;
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Comment: оберни запрос в promise  потом используй then или же async await

Comment: Дополнил, так ты иммел ввиду? Но не сработало!

Comment: сори new XMLHttpRequest() не использовал не вижу где отправка где ответ теоретически let answer = await ответ от сервера и тогда проверить answer

Comment: Да он дальше продолжает выполнять файлы js и загрузку html,чего мне и не надо

Comment: не сработало потому как запрос должен вернуть промис используй для запроса fetch знаю что он точно возврашает промис но по любому тебе нужны промисы для того что хочеш реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался простым.

```
 xhr.open("POST",url,**false**);
```